# Visual Studio 2013 Express has no MS-Reports Template Installed

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, rdlc, sql-server-data-tools

When I Google and look up how to add a RDLC report to my Visual Studio 2013 Project I get the answer i'd expect, usually "In the Templates pane, select Report or Report Wizard"

This article is one of them: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252067(v=VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252067%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Nowhere can I find anything about "what if there is no Reports section" in your installed Templates

For the last month I thought this was because I needed to download SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2013. Yesterday I installed this. As a result I now appear to have a new version of Visual Studio 2013 called "Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Integrated)". It has a purple icon and loads with a black splash image

My Project is currently running and being developed in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web which has a green icon

If I try to load my project into the new Integrated Shell VS 2013 I get errors. What I really want is just to have the template available so I can add RDLC reports

I have already used MuGet to install MvcReportViewer and set my web config etc and references. Following instructions at https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcReportViewer/

Now I need to create an RDLC but have no Template to do so

Could it be that VS-2013 Express has this feature turned off, because if I go into Help/About VS2013 Express for Web it has SQL Server Data Tools 12.0.30919.1 as an Installed product

Any comments appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't use VS 2013 Express to edit RDLC files.  It requires at least the professional version.

See: http://community.dynamics.com/nav/b/navteam/archive/2013/12/19/microsoft-visual-studio-2013-now-supported-for-rdlc-report-design.aspx

You can, however, create them in Sql Server Reporting Services, which is part of the advanced version of Sql Server Express Edition, using SQL Server Business Intelligence Developer Studio (BIDS) Express.

Comment: And you can get a "Developer Edition" SQL Server license for ~$50. That would include the necessary tools. You may even be able to download the standalone tools for this. Look for SSDT-BI and you should find the things to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download 
 (Microsoft Report viewer 2012 run-time)
& Report Builder3 
- First is the tool that display & Print Report.

- Report Builder is the tool that you can design report with it.



You Must have SQL Server 2012 Installed